# "He would have never do that" is this correct?

Tags: grammar

"He would have never do that"

is this correct ?

i want to say a person would've never do a certain thing in the past ( maybe he is dead right now )

Comment: Putting aside the word never, use *have done* for standard English: He would have never done that. I'd prefer 'He would *never* have done that," but your version has slightly different emphasis.

Comment: He never would have done that. That's the most emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

"He never would have done that" sounds better but in your sentence i suppose the only thing that needs changing is "do" to "done" so "He would not have ever done that"